# How do I add a tool tip to a span element?

Tags: html, css

In the following code, I want a tool-tip to come up when the user hovers the span, how do I do that?  I don't want to use any links.

```
<span> text </span>
```

Answer (score 810, accepted):

Here's the simple, built-in way:

```html
<span title="My tip">text</span>
```

That gives you plain text tooltips.  If you want rich tooltips, with formatted HTML in them, you'll need to use a library to do that.  Fortunately [there are loads of those](https://www.appcues.com/blog/73-tooltip-plugins-made-with-jquery-css-javascript-or-more).

Comment: But does this work if there isn't any text in the span? Say for example an empty span with a bg-image?

Comment: @UGS: Are you sure your element is the size you think it is?  Try giving it a pink background like mine.  :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot.! But i just used tipsy.js and it looks better that what I wanted. :D And this article aided in my confusion : http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/html_401/article.php/3479661/HTML-40-SPAN-Tag.htm where it says that the tooltip works for the "text"

Comment: Hi, Can someone clarify if this is standard in some/all HTML flavor?

Comment: @jonathan: It's been standard since at least HTML4: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-title

Answer (score 127):

### Custom Tooltips with pure CSS - no JavaScript needed:

#### [Example here (with code)](http://jsfiddle.net/8nnwytbL/) / [Full screen example](http://jsfiddle.net/8nnwytbL/show)

As an alternative to the default `title` attribute tooltips, you can make your own custom CSS tooltips using `:before`/`:after` [pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) and HTML5 [`data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).

Using the provided CSS, you can add a tooltip to an element using the `data-tooltip` attribute.

You can also control the position of the custom tooltip using the `data-tooltip-position` attribute (accepted values: `top`/`right`/`bottom`/`left`).

For instance, the following will add a tooltop positioned at the bottom of the span element.

```
<span data-tooltip="Custom tooltip text." data-tooltip-position="bottom">Custom bottom tooltip.</span>
```

[image]

#### How does this work?

You can display the custom tooltips with pseudo elements by retrieving the custom attribute values using the [**`attr()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) function.

```
[data-tooltip]:before {
    content: attr(data-tooltip);
}
```

In terms of positioning the tooltip, just use the [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) and change the placement based on the attribute's value.

#### [Example here (with code)](http://jsfiddle.net/8nnwytbL/) / [Full screen example](http://jsfiddle.net/8nnwytbL/show)

**Full CSS used in the example** - customize this to your needs.

```
[data-tooltip] {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    cursor: help;
    padding: 4px;
}
/* Tooltip styling */
[data-tooltip]:before {
    content: attr(data-tooltip);
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    min-width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
/* Dynamic horizontal centering */
[data-tooltip-position="top"]:before,
[data-tooltip-position="bottom"]:before {
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
/* Dynamic vertical centering */
[data-tooltip-position="right"]:before,
[data-tooltip-position="left"]:before {
    top: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
[data-tooltip-position="top"]:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}
[data-tooltip-position="right"]:before {
    left: 100%;
    margin-left: 6px;
}
[data-tooltip-position="bottom"]:before {
    top: 100%;
    margin-top: 6px;
}
[data-tooltip-position="left"]:before {
    right: 100%;
    margin-right: 6px;
}

/* Tooltip arrow styling/placement */
[data-tooltip]:after {
    content: '';
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
}
/* Dynamic horizontal centering for the tooltip */
[data-tooltip-position="top"]:after,
[data-tooltip-position="bottom"]:after {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -6px;
}
/* Dynamic vertical centering for the tooltip */
[data-tooltip-position="right"]:after,
[data-tooltip-position="left"]:after {
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -6px;
}
[data-tooltip-position="top"]:after {
    bottom: 100%;
    border-width: 6px 6px 0;
    border-top-color: #000;
}
[data-tooltip-position="right"]:after {
    left: 100%;
    border-width: 6px 6px 6px 0;
    border-right-color: #000;
}
[data-tooltip-position="bottom"]:after {
    top: 100%;
    border-width: 0 6px 6px;
    border-bottom-color: #000;
}
[data-tooltip-position="left"]:after {
    right: 100%;
    border-width: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    border-left-color: #000;
}
/* Show the tooltip when hovering */
[data-tooltip]:hover:before,
[data-tooltip]:hover:after {
    display: block;
    z-index: 50;
}
```

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge Really? I'll look in to that at some point. Thanks.

Comment: Yes I just tested it and also wasn't surprised it didn't work .Good old IE! ;)

Comment: @JoshCrozier it helped a lot

Comment: actually, I think this should be the best answer. It perfectly covers my needs. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can content be styled?

Answer (score 22):

In most browsers, the title attribute will render as a tooltip, and is generally flexible as to what sorts of elements it'll work with.

```
<span title="This will show as a tooltip">Mouse over for a tooltip!</span>
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" title="Link to stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow.com</a>
<img src="something.png" alt="Something" title="Something">
```

All of those will render tooltips in most every browser.

Answer (score 12):

For the basic tooltip, you want:

```html
<span title="This is my tooltip"> Hover on me to see tooltip! </span>
```

Answer (score 6):

The [`title`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-title-attribute) attribute will be used as the text for tooltip by the browser. If you want to apply style to it, consider using some libraries, e.g. [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/).