# add title attribute from css

Tags: html, css

How to add `title='mandatory'` from css to the following

```
     <label class='mandatory'>Name</label>

.mandatory
{
background-image:url(/media/img/required.gif);
background-position:top right;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
padding-right:10px;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: For anyone reading this in the future, you can create [custom tooltips with CSS using pseudo elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055581/how-do-i-add-a-tool-tip-to-a-span-element/25836471#25836471) you can either specify the text value in a custom `data-*` attribute or the `content` property. See this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055581/how-do-i-add-a-tool-tip-to-a-span-element/25836471#25836471

Comment: For anyone wanting to use browser built-in tooltips for this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/46889216/1709903

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can't. CSS is a presentation language. It isn't designed to add content (except for the very trivial with `:before` and `:after`).

Answer (score 94):

Well, although it's not actually possible to change the title attribute, it is possible to show a tooltip completely from CSS.
You can check a working version out at http://jsfiddle.net/HzH3Z/5/.

What you can do is style the label:after selector and give it display:none, and set its content from CSS. You can then change the display attribute to display:block on label:hover:after, and it will show.
Like this:

```css
label::after {
  content: "my tooltip";
  padding: 2px;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
  right: -30px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fef4c5;
  border: 1px solid #d4b943;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -ms-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
label:hover::after {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: +1, you can even use data attributes as the source for the tooltip. [Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HzH3Z/54/). (This way your content remains in HTML, and your CSS again only is used to tell the browser how to show it).

Comment: 1+ Here is a [similar answer using custom `data-*` attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055581/how-do-i-add-a-tool-tip-to-a-span-element/25836471#25836471) for content http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055581/how-do-i-add-a-tool-tip-to-a-span-element/25836471#25836471 it also supports positioning.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  The question was, essentially, how can I add a tooltip using css?  This answers it the best.

Comment: I would avoid this sort of thing when the information is important, as otherwise it will not be available to screenreaders and a11y users.

Comment: I agree @stephenmurdoch that is definitely a concern.

Comment: Both a11y and i18n would be an issue for the content coming from the CSS.

Comment: Note: `:after` should be replaced with `::after`. While both work, it's technically not a pseudo-class but a pseudo-element which use a double colon.

Answer (score 19):

Quentin is correct, it can't be done with CSS. If you want to add a `title` attribute, you can do it with JavaScript. Here's an example using jQuery:

```
$('label').attr('title','mandatory');
```

Comment: I tried it $(".mandatory").attr('title','mandatory');
  somehow the title doesnt show up

Comment: Yes i did but this was done in my base page where some other page can be included i dont know why its not working

Comment: can you post a link? hard to say without seeing it. try enclosing the above with `$(document).ready(function() {` and `});` so that the jquery waits until the document (and thus target element) has loaded before running.

Answer (score 5):

**It is possible to imitate this with HTML & CSS**

If you really really want dynamically applied tooltips to work, this (not so performance and architecture friendly) solution can allow you to use browser rendered tooltips without resorting to JS. I can imagine situations where this would be better than JS.

If you have a fixed subset of title attribute values, then you can generate additional elements server-side and let the browser read title from another element positioned above the original one using CSS.

Example:

```css
div{
  position: relative;
}
div > span{
  display: none;
}

.pick-tooltip-1 > .tooltip-1, .pick-tooltip-2 > .tooltip-2{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="pick-tooltip-1">
  Hover to see first tooltip
  <span class="tooltip-1" title="Tooltip 1"></span>
  <span class="tooltip-2" title="Tooltip 2"></span>
</div>

<div class="pick-tooltip-2">
  Hover to see second tooltip
  <span class="tooltip-1" title="Tooltip 1"></span>
  <span class="tooltip-2" title="Tooltip 2"></span>
</div>
```

*Note: It's not recommended for large scale applications because of unnecessary HTML, possible content repetitions and the fact that your extra elements for tooltip would steal mouse events (text selection, etc)*

Answer (score 4):

As Quentin and other suggested this cannot totally be done with css(partially done with content attribute of css). Instead you should use javascript/jQuery to achieve this,

JS:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("mandatory")[0].title = "mandatory";
```

or using jQuery:

```
$('.mandatory').attr('title','mandatory');
```

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('mandatory')[0].setAttribute('title', 'mandatory');

$('.jmandatory').attr('title', 'jmandatory');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Place the Mouse Over the following elements to see the title,
<br/><br/>
<b><label class="mandatory">->Javascript Mandatory</label></b>
<br/><br/>
<b><label class="jmandatory">->jQuery Mandatory</label></b>
```

Answer (score 3):

Can do, with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mandatory').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('title', $(this).attr('class'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

While currently not possible with CSS, there is a proposal to enable this functionality called [Cascading Attribute Sheets](https://web.archive.org/web/20150720091350/http://www.webmonkey.com/2012/09/like-css-wrap-your-head-around-cascading-attribute-sheets/).

Answer (score -1):

On the one hand, the title is helpful as a tooltip when moving the mouse over the element. This could be solved with CSS-> element::after.
But it is much more important as an aid for visually impaired people (topic handicap-free website). And for this it MUST be included as an attribute in the HTML element. Everything else is junk, botch, idiot stuff ...!