# Create an attribute with CSS3

Tags: css

For each element of class "new" I want to show a title on hover. So using jquery I do this:

```
$(".new").attr("title", "import the new item");
```

Is it possible to create this attribute via CSS? Since we can create content I thought maybe this is possible too. So I am looking for something like

```
.new
{
    attr(title): "import new item"; // create property via css
}
```

Comment: double of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136855/add-title-attribute-from-css

Comment: No, it is not possible. CSS isn't used for DOM manipulation, just presentation.

Comment: No, this does not exist for that attribute. The styling is limited.
See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383148/is-it-possible-to-style-a-title-and-with-css-or-js

Comment: found the duplicate some minutes after posting but since useful responses came in, voted for close instead of deleting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a proposal to enable this kind of functionality, called [Cascasing Attribute Sheets](http://www.webmonkey.com/2012/09/like-css-wrap-your-head-around-cascading-attribute-sheets/).

Comment: excellent answer, thx. you maybe have some really good css3 resource(s) to find such things?

Comment: If only this question wasn't a duplicate, you would have gotten an up-vote for teaching me something interesting. If you post it in the original question, you got my vote

Comment: @citykid it's not currently possible with CSS, indeed jQuery is your best bet.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum thanks, I also posted this link there.