# Set innerHTML as title attribute using css only

Tags: html, css, tooltip, title

I want to set title attribute whatever innerHTML text is there in a span.
I know we can set css style based on the title attribute. But don't know how to set innerHTML as title using only CSS.

Eg. below is the span that I have.

```
<span id="spnData">A1234567890BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ01234567890123</span>
```

And below is what I want to achieve.

```
<span id="spnData" title="A1234567890BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ01234567890123">A1234567890BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ01234567890123</span>
```

Its dynamic control and I can not set it directly. I just want to know can we set innerHTML as title attribute using css only.

Note: I want to use pure CSS to do this and don't want to use any CSS plugin or JavaScript/Jquery. I know best choice here is Jquery but I want to know is it possible with CSS or not.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136855/add-title-attribute-from-css

Comment: @linktoahref I know how to do it using script. My question is 'is it possible using CSS?' thanks

Comment: Well if you go through the answers it says NO!

Comment: BoltClock.. My question was different by the way.

Answer (score 0):

With pure CSS, it's currently impossible.