# Scrape title attribute from CSS with rvest

Tags: css, r, web-scraping, css-selectors, rvest

I use rvest to scrape web data. 
I have the following CSS code from a website:

```
<abbr class="intabbr" title="2.856.890">2,9M</abbr>
```

I scrape this data with

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
n <- read_html("https://www.last.fm/de/music/Fang+Island")
n %>%
html_node("abbr") %>%
html_text()
```

This gives me "2M", but what I would like to get is the "2.856.890".

I am not very knowledgeable in CSS: Is it possible to get the information which I want by the changing the expression in html_node()?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136855/add-title-attribute-from-css) suggests that it is not possible, however [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055581/how-do-i-add-a-tool-tip-to-a-span-element/25836471#25836471) suggests that it might be possible since it pops up as a tooltip on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `html_attr` to get a tag's attribute:

```
n %>%
  html_node("abbr") %>%
  html_attr("title")
```