# How to create a box when mouse over text in pure CSS?

Tags: css

I have tried many times to do this, but it has not worked out yet.

When I mouse over this text

[image]

Then it must show me this box

[image]

I want to achieve this effect purely with CSS if anybody can do this.

Comment: Perhaps you may be interested in this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055581/how-do-i-add-a-tool-tip-to-a-span-element/25836471#25836471

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can write like this:

**CSS**

```
span{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F8F8F8;
    border: 5px solid #DFDFDF;
    color: #717171;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    top: -80px;
    left:-30px;
    display:none;
    padding:0 20px;

}
span:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-10px;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    border-bottom:5px solid #dfdfdf;
    border-right:5px solid #dfdfdf;
    background:#f8f8f8;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-5px;
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    transform:rotate(45deg);
}
p{
    margin:100px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
}

p:hover span{
    display:block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p>Hover here<span>some text here ?</span></p>
```

Check this  http://jsfiddle.net/UNs9J/1/

Comment: woah, that's nice :) Do you know what the compatibility is? I can see that the rotates (the 'arrow') will probably not work in IE / opera, but any other limits?

Comment: rotate work in opera & for IE you can use IE filter http://www.boogdesign.com/b2evo/index.php/element-rotation-ie-matrix-filter?blog=2

Answer (score 3):

You can easily make this **CSS Tool Tip** through simple code :-

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
a.info{
    position:relative; /*this is the key*/
    color:#000;
    top:100px;
    left:50px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
  }



a.info span{display: none}

a.info:hover span{ /*the span will display just on :hover state*/
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:-60px;
    width:15em;
    border:5px solid #0cf;
    background-color:#cff; color:#000;
    text-align: center;
    padding:10px;
  }

  a.info:hover span:after{ /*the span will display just on :hover state*/
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-11px;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    border-bottom:5px solid #0cf;
    border-right:5px solid #0cf;
    background:#cff;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-5px;
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    transform:rotate(45deg);
  }


</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" class="info">Shailender Arora <span>TOOLTIP</span></a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/ebucoz/25/edit

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it by toggling between **display: block** on hover and **display:none** without hover to produce the effect.

Answer (score 1):

This is a small tweak on the other answers. If you have nested divs you can include more exciting content such as H1s in your popup.

CSS

```
div.appear {
    width: 250px; 
    border: #000 2px solid;
    background:#F8F8F8;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    left:15px;
    display:none;
    padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
    z-index: 1000000;
}
div.hover  {
    cursor:pointer;
    width: 5px;
}
div.hover:hover div.appear {
    display:block;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="hover">
<img src="questionmark.png"/>
    <div class="appear">
       <h1>My popup</h1>Hitherto and whenceforth.
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem with these solutions is that everything after this in the page gets shifted when the popup is displayed, ie, the rest of the page jumps downwards to 'make space'. The only way I could fix this was by making position:absolute and removing the top and left CSS tags.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly what they said, it will work.

In the parent element stablish a max-height.

I'm taking **sandeep** example and adding the max-height and if required you can add max-width property. The text will stay where It should stay (If possible, in some cases you will need to change some values to make it stay in there)

```
span{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F8F8F8;
    border: 5px solid #DFDFDF;
    color: #717171;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    top: -80px;
    left:-30px;
    display:none;
    padding:0 20px;
}

span:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-10px;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    border-bottom:5px solid #dfdfdf;
    border-right:5px solid #dfdfdf;
    background:#f8f8f8;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-5px;
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
     transform:rotate(45deg);
}

p{
    margin:100px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
    max-height: 10px;
}

p:hover span{
    display:block;
}
```

> max-height in the **p** paragraph, second to last one, last line.

Test it before rating it useless.

Comment: How does this add anything over the existing answers?

Comment: Added max-height and max-width properties, nothing is shifted when the cursor is upon the text and the box is being shown.