# How to create a css hoverover box with two section

Tags: html, css

I have used the following [How to create a box when mouse over text in pure CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243440/how-to-creat-a-box-when-mouse-over-text-in-pure-css)

and switch the position of the cursor and the placement

```
span{
    background:#F8F8F8;
    border: 5px solid #DFDFDF;
    color: #717171;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 150px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    left:60px;
    display:none;
    padding:0 20px;

}
span:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:40px;
    right: 135px;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    border-bottom:5px solid #dfdfdf;
    border-right:5px solid #dfdfdf;
    background:#f8f8f8;
    margin-left:-10px;
    -moz-transform:rotate(135deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(135deg);
    transform:rotate(135deg);
}
p{
    margin:100px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
}

p:hover span{
    display:block;
}

<p>Hover here<span>some text here ?</span></p>
```

Here is the [fiddle] (http://jsfiddle.net/beerbuddha/4kjnb4e5/)

I need a split 25%(header) with different background color and the rest (75%) to be a different color and to hold text and an image.

I tried the  approach and what happens is that the display:none doesnt work anymore at all and the hover box it self break.

Im slightly lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple. You change html:

```
<div class="div-hover">Hover here
  <div class="div-tooltip">
    <div class="tooltip-header">some text here ?</div>
    <div class="tooltip-body">some text body some text body</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Full code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4kjnb4e5/2/)

Comment: Not quite, I need it to look liek a SOLID heading (think table). So the top part would be where I can put in bold a title. Then the rest is the body with a description. If that helps describing my needs. Appreciated the response.

Comment: So you change they to <div> elements. I have change my code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4kjnb4e5/2/)

Comment: perfect - please switch your answer around so that you can get the spotlight