# Will we have option to change color for span title

Tags: html, css

I like to change my Image title font color which is showing as tooltip.

```
 <span id="pencilIcon" class="fa fa-pencil" title="Add/Edit Friendly Label&#13;Max 15 Characters"></span>
```

Here I want Max 15 Characters in red color. I tried font color showing like this
[image]

Comment: You'll have to use your own tooltips. e.g. http://qtip2.com/

Comment: That is browser behaviour, and is not modifiable. You'll need to implement a custom tooltip solution.

Comment: No, you cannot change the color of that. You can create custom tool-tips using the method mentioned here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25214632/how-can-i-create-custom-tooltips-with-css-pseudoelements/25214884#25214884. That thread will help with custom tool-tips. If you want to change color of only a part of the text, you will need to customize it further.

Answer (score 0):

if you need change color of your title only way is use css tooltip.

For example:
http://www.menucool.com/tooltip/css-tooltip