# Is it possible to use the hover pseudoclass to offset a box 20px from some text?

Tags: html, css

I have a single line of text:

```
<p> this is some text <b class="tryHover">hover over here</b> </p>
```

And when the cursor is over the text "hover over here" I'm trying to get a box with some content to pop up and i'm trying to do it all in css.

So in my css file i have:

```
.tryHover:hover{

}
```

I think I get what the above does and it lets me change the properties of the text "hover over here" when the cursor is over it. eg change background-color, etc.

But what I would like to do is have a box that "pops" up that is say 20px below the text when I hover over it.

So I thought I'd create a box class like:

```
.box {             
   width: 
   height:
   border: 
}
```

But I'm struggling to figure out if it's possible to make that box appear when hovering over the text using CSS alone.

Thanks.

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered) might help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create custom tooltips with css pseudoelements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25214632/how-can-i-create-custom-tooltips-with-css-pseudoelements)

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17391194/tooltip-with-html-content-without-javascript) also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make box inside the `<b>` tag and use `position:absolute` to `.box` for the position adjustment.

*Remember to set the `position:relative` of the parent of the `.box` div.*

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 25px;
  display: none;
}

.tryHover {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tryHover:hover .box {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p> this is some text <b class="tryHover">hover over here<span class="box"></span></b>
</p>
```

Comment: Thx. But is it necessary to have the <span> tag? Can it be done say with just <b class="tryHover box" ?

Comment: @Mike you want to show a _box with some content_ when hover over `tryHover`...so you need two elements....one which you want to show and one the other on hover you want to show the box....

Answer (score 1):

The key is nesting your `.box` (with `display:none` set by default) inside `.tryHover` and then giving it `display: block` inside of `.tryHover:hover .box` style block:

```css
.box {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 5px;
}

.tryHover {
  position: relative;
}

.tryHover:hover .box {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>
  This is some text 
  <strong class="tryHover">hover over here
    <span class="box">Boxed text</span>
  </strong>
</p>
```