# How to show tooltip On click event Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I show a tooltip by clicking on a button with   JavaScript ?

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
<div class="tooltiptext">
<button>click me</button>
  <span >Tooltip text
  
  </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;

  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

The tooltip is showing while doing hover. But I want to show tooltip while using on click event using only JavaScript how will I do that. Please help me.

Comment: if you click on "hover me" you want to show tooltip?

Comment: yes @Ifaruki how will I do that

Answer (score 4):

I whipped up a toggle using ES5. I wasn't sure if you were using a transpiler. I made a couple of tweaks to your CSS.

Depending on your implementation, this should be refactored to use event delegation.

```js
var tooltip = document.querySelector('.tooltip')

tooltip.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (this.classList.contains('active')) {
    this.classList.remove('active');
  } else {
    this.classList.add('active');
  }
  
});
```

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;

  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip.active .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
<div class="tooltiptext">
<button>click me</button>
  <span >Tooltip text

  </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following setup:

**html**

```
<button id="button1">click me</button>
<div class="tooltiptext">
 <span >Tooltip text</span>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;

  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

**js**

```
var button1 = document.querySelectorAll('#button1');
button1.onclick = buttonClicked;
function buttonClicked(){
  var tooltip = document.querySelectorAll('.tooltiptext');
  tooltip.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

Comment: @PranjalDeb Kindly refer this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want something like this. When you click on "hover me" it shows your tooltip and you can close it with X

```
<div onmousedown="show()" class="tooltip">
  Hover over me
  <div id="tooltip" onmouseup="hide()" class="tooltiptext">
    <span>Tooltip text </span><span class="close">X</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}
.tooltip:hover {
   cursor: pointer;
}
.close {
  color: red;
}
.close:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  display: none;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;

  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.block {
  display: block !important;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
 function hide() {
  document.getElementById("tooltip").classList.remove("block");
}
function show() {
  document.getElementById("tooltip").classList.add("block");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple way of achieving this is by using the event listener to change the display style from `none` to `block` and vice versa.

For it to work properly is important to **add the style attribute to the tooltip element** like so: `<tooltip id='tooltip' style='display:none'>`

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn'),
      tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (tooltip.style.display === "none") {
      tooltip.style.display = "block";
  }
  else{
    tooltip.style.display  = "none";
  }
})
```

```css
#tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top:5px;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div style='position:relative'>
  <button id='btn' style='cursor:pointer'>Try me</button>
  <tooltip id='tooltip' style='display:none'>
    Some text here
  </tooltip>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="tooltip">
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Hover over me</a>
<div class="tooltiptext">
<button>click me</button>
  <span >Tooltip text

  </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try using focus

```
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;

  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
.tooltip a{ color: inherit; text-decoration: none; }
.tooltip a:focus+.tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```