# Display text under cursor

Tags: javascript, html

Whe mouse pointer placed on an element I want to show some text. For example if you place your cursor on upvote of an answer, it shows "This answer is useful". You can see it in below image. I did't even know how to search this.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a [`title` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes) to the element. That's what's done in the image above.

```
<a class="vote-up-off" title="This answer is useful.">up vote</a>
```

---

If you want a custom tooltip, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055581/how-do-i-add-a-tool-tip-to-a-span-element/25836471#25836471). You would basically use a combination of pseudo elements and custom `data-*` attributes. You would give the pseudo elements a `content` value of `attr(data-tooltip)` in order to access the `data-tooltip` attribute, for instance.