# Change font-family of mouse-over text

Tags: html, css, asp.net

If you have a tag with the attribute `title` like this:

`<span title="this is mouseover text">some text</span>`

and you hover over it with your mouse, you will see "this is mouseover text".

My question is, can you change the font-family of "this is mouseover text"? Is that font-family that shows up the font-family of your browser? I tried even putting in escaped html code with  tags to try and change that font-family but it didn't work.

Is this even possible?

EDIT: Is this possible maybe in asp.net??? Using code behind?

Comment: I don't know about a way to change that but you can use tooltip library which is like title but better with option to style everything with CSS

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to format an HTML tooltip (title attribute)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484137/is-it-possible-to-format-an-html-tooltip-title-attribute)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to customize the basic `title` element. You can try using different [tooltip](http://www.opentip.org/) [libraies](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/). [Seriously,](http://projects.nickstakenburg.com/tipped) [there](http://darsa.in/tooltip/) [are](http://designshack.net/articles/javascript/25-useful-resources-for-creating-tooltips-with-javascript-or-css/) [dozens](http://www.webdesignbooth.com/15-jquery-plugins-to-create-an-user-friendly-tooltip/). Most of these use JavaScript, but there are ways to do it [with pure CSS, too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25836471/3780112).

These libraries/methods usually create a new, hidden by default element which will become visible when you hover over their anchor. They are easy to use, too, and offer great customization options.