# How to display a definition on hover over a word that is in a sentence?

Tags: javascript, html, css

After writing down a set of rules for a website, I want to give certain words a definition. My idea was that it would be best when a person hovers over a word, that the definition will pop up below or at the top of the word, whilst the text around the word itself remains in place.

I have looked all over and I cannot find a proper way to do this. I have offcourse looked at: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_tooltip.asp

This is very close to what I want to achieve, but I cannot seem to find out on how to get text in front and after the word I want to hover over and then display a definition.

Hopefully I am clear in my wording here.

On a side note, only html, css and javascript should be used.

Example:

```
<p>Rule number 1: Please be respectful in our community.</p>
```

I would want a hover on the word respectful that displays a text above it with a definition.

Comment: Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055581/how-do-i-add-a-tool-tip-to-a-span-element

Comment: This question should never have been closed, as it is not a duplicate of the linked question. The linked question is about adding a tooltip to a span. This question is about adding a definition as you hover over a term. The answers to the two questions are different. And while you *may* hack one by using the other, they are not the same, and not interchangable.

Comment: @IanBoyd the question suggested as similar to this, includes both ways to add a tooltip via the `title` attribute and using pseudo-elements via css rules. The content itself is irrilevant but the way to achieve the result is the same

Comment: @DiegoD And perhaps the way to achieve the very different questions is the same. But they are very different questions. And...different answers. And even if both had the **exact** same answer, they are **not** duplicate questions.

Comment: @ianboyd let's put it this way: it's an old question that has nothing to be added anyway. The answers were given and they were upvoted. Those answers by the way perfectly match with the same answers given to the similar question hinted except for the `dfn` element that it's interesting to know about but still don't change the fact it's the question to be similar.. the answer should be given to the other original question. And yet those answers are missing the shades of pseudo elements strategy. The lines are shaded of course but let's be honest. If you split the hair there's no line anymore

Comment: otherwise you'll keep asking the same question again and again just changing the subject: how to add a tooltip for the name? how to add the tooltip for the description? how to add the tooltip for...

Comment: I was victim of this same game pretty recently (yesterday) and I was answered with something not only unrelated but even sounding like a joke using words that don't even exist. But yet it's a matter of drawing the line at some point

Comment: @DiegoD *"Those answers by the way perfectly match with the same answers"* That question does not have answers that answer this question. That question does not mention `dfn` at all; **nor should it** because that isn't what was asked. This is a different question. The reason you know this is an entirely different question, is because it has an entirely different answer. **So different**, in fact, that a custom HTML element was created for it. This question is not a duplicate of that question. That question does not answer this question. This question does not answer that question. Re-open.

Comment: question of 2019 reopened with answer already given. Now it can be further answered. Maybe the element dfn2 will come out

Answer (score 3):

There is already a tag specifically for this, if you don't mind holding your mouse over it for a moment, the DEFINITION tag or <dfn>. By default, it italicizes the text, but you can change that styling however you'd like to. This is going to be more semantically accurate than just using something like a span or div, but it doesn't really matter which you do. It's the `title` on the element that does the magic.

```html
<p>Rule number 1: Please be <dfn title="don't be a jerk">respectful</dfn> in our community.</p>
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as my answer.

Comment: True, though semantically speaking, this one is also going to be more correct, and unfortunately it didn't tell me your answer until after I finished writing mine.

Comment: This is not the correct usage of the `dfn` element. The `title` attribute has to contain the term being defined, not the definition itself. The context (in a `p`, `dd` or `section` element) has to be the definition. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dfn

Comment: Future me agrees with you. To get the desired result and also follow more closely to the standard, `abbr` could be used, but that's not quite semantically true, either.

Comment: Well, that's disappointing. I'm going to go with `<dfn title="the definition">the term</dfn>` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `title` attribute on a `<span>` element (hover for a second over `respectful`:

```html
<p>Rule number 1: Please be <span title="feeling or showing deference and respect">respectful</span> in our community.</p>
```

Or, you could use the HTML5 [`<dfn>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dfn) (definition) tag for semantics, although you'd still need the `title` attribute:

```html
<p>Rule number 1: Please be <dfn title="feeling or showing deference and respect">respectful</dfn> in our community.</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for stealing my answer as your edit.